# Mapstruct: @InheritInverseConfiguration --> There is no suitable result type constructor for reversing this method

Tags: java, mapstruct

I try to use mapstruct feature @InheritInverseConfiguration. But it gives me the following error: There is no suitable result type constructor for reversing this method.
But the generated Impl look pretty good.

```
@Mapper(uses = {
  BOIdMapper.class,
  DateMapper.class,
  CarVOFactory.class,
})
public interface CarMapper {
   CarMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CarMapper .class);

   @Mappings({
     @Mapping(source = "VOKey", target = "id"),
     @Mapping(source = "gueltAb", target = "gueltigAb")
   })
   Car map(CarVO carVO);

   @InheritInverseConfiguration
   CarVO map(Car car);

   public class CarVOFactory {
      public CarVO createCarVO() {
         return VOFactory.createVO(CarVO.class);
      }
   }
}
```

This is the POJO Car

```
public class Car {

    private String id;
    private LocalDate gueltigAb;
    ...
}
```

This is the other Car-Class:

```
public interface CarVO extends ... {
    void setVOKey (VOKey<CAR> voKey);
}
```

Comment: How does the Impl look like? If it really gives you that error and everything is OK, then this most probably is a bug. Can you please open an issue on our [issue tracker](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues)